# Assigning form data for Ajax Request with triggerHandler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using exactly the same JQuery/Ajax call for other forms which work fine, so I have absolutely no idea why this isnt working for my 3rd form on this page. Maybe you have an idea what this might be.

I want to do a Ajax Request for a form which needs to be send.

Here is my index.php which includes the form:

```
<div id="addSmurfForm" class="full_w">
    <div class="h_title">Add new smurfs - PHP Loader</div>
    <form name="form" id="test" method="post">

        <div class="element">
            <select name="accounttype" id="accounttype" class="required">
                <option value="gifting" selected="selected">Gifting accounts</option>
                <option value="fullip">Full IP accounts</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="element">
            <label for="priority">Accounts <span class="red">(required)</span></label>
            <textarea class="text required" name="accountData" id="accountData" placeholder="<?php echo $deintext="tenur2es67|Tbuvp928|EUW|54469c27c687b332339627\nkibbutzm65|K5ph88|EUW|54469ba0dec3e703865612"; ?>" style="height: 250px;"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="sendOrder" class="entry">
            <button type="submit" id="addSmurfsbtn" class="add">Load Accounts</button>
            <button id="resetbtn" class="cancel">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div id="addSmurfsResult">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My JQuery / Ajax Request:

```
$( "#addSmurfsbtn" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $( "#test" ).triggerHandler( "submitForm" );
    if ( form_data ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/loadsmurfs.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function( data ) {
                $('#addSmurfsResult').append(data).hide().slideDown("slow");
                //alertify.alert("Done");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My loadsmurfs.php:

```
<?php
    echo "test";
?>
```

When I tried to alert "form_data" it alerts "undefined" so I think the problem is something with assigning the form_data to my variable, but I can't find the mistake. I really hope you can help me, I am struggling with this for 2 hours now.

Comment: use `submit` instead `submitForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a `submitForm` or `submit` handler defined. The following should do it:

```
$( "#addSmurfsbtn" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "#test" ).triggerHandler('submit');
});
$('#test').on('submit', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/loadsmurfs.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {
                $('#addSmurfsResult').append(data).hide().slideDown("slow");
                //alertify.alert("Done");
            }
        });
});
```

**Special Note**

It is always advisable to let the `submit` button in a form do what it was designed to do, but since you do not have a submit button, you just need to trigger the submit event when the target button is clicked

```
$( "#addSmurfsbtn" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "#test" ).submit();
});
$('#test').on('submit', function() {
     //....
});
```

Comment: Still a problem with assigning the form_data :/. http://puu.sh/cv8Hf/7d0e35fe1a.png Here the pic what Google Chrome says.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Do you need to update the opening paragraph in your question?

Comment: You can use the network tab in dev tools to check what data is being sent to your server in the ajax all. In your form I do not see any form control with `name="smurfData"` ... also make sure that the spelling is the same in PHP as in the form. Field names are case sensitive as well.